# Monitor.Enter vs Monitor.Wait

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I'm still unsure on the differences between these two calls. From MSDN,

`Monitor.Enter(Object)` Acquires an exclusive lock on the specified object.

`Monitor.Wait(Object)` Releases the lock on an object and blocks the current thread until it reacquires the lock.

From that I assume that Monitor.Wait is the same as Monitor.Enter except that it releases the lock on the object first before reacquiring.

Does the current thread have to have the lock in the first place? How could a different thread force a release on a lock of an object? Why would the same thread want to reacquire a lock?

Comment: Enter/Exit is for mutual exclusion, Wait/Pulse(All) is for waiting and signaling. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [MSDN: Monitor.Wait Method(Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateab679.aspx)

> SynchronizationLockException: The calling thread does not own the lock for the specified object.

In other words: You can only call `Monitor.Wait(Object)`, when you **already own** the lock, whereas you call `Monitor.Enter(Object)` in order to **acquire** the lock.

As for why `Monitor.Wait` is needed: If your thread realizes, that it is lacking information to continue execution (e.g. it's waiting for a signal), you might want to let other threads enter the critical section, because not all threads have the same prerequisites.

For the waiting thread to continue execution, you will need to call `Monitor.Pulse(Object)` or `Monitor.PulseAll(Object)` **before** releasing the lock (otherwise, you're going to get the same kind of exception as with `Monitor.Wait(Object)`).

Keep in mind, that the next thread that acquires the lock after a pulse and after the lock was released, is not necessarily the thread that received the pulse.

Also keep in mind, that receiving a pulse, is not equivalent to having your condition met. You might still need to wait just a little longer:

```
// make sure to synchronize this correctly ;)
while (ConditionNotMet)
{
    Monitor.Wait(mutex);
    if (ConditionNotMet) // We woke up, but our condition is still not met
        Monitor.Pulse(mutex); // Perhaps another waiting thread wants to wake up?
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider this example:

```
public class EnterExitExample
{
    private object myLock;
    private bool running;

    private void ThreadProc1()
    {
        while (running)
        {
            lock (myLock)
            {
                // Do stuff here...
            }
            Thread.Yield();
        }
    }

    private void ThreadProc2()
    {
        while (running)
        {
            lock (myLock)
            {
                // Do other stuff here...
            }
            Thread.Yield();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you have two threads, each waiting for lock, then doing their stuff, then releasing the lock. The `lock (myLock)` syntax is just sugar for `Monitor.Enter(myLock)` and `Monitor.Exit(myLock)`.

Let us now look at a more complicated example, where `Wait` and `Pulse` come into play.

```
public class PulseWaitExample
{
    private Queue<object> queue;
    private bool running;

    private void ProducerThreadProc()
    {
        while (running)
        {
            object produced = ...; // Do production stuff here.
            lock (queue)
            {
                queue.Enqueue(produced);
                Monitor.Pulse(queue);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ConsumerThreadProc()
    {
        while (running)
        {
            object toBeConsumed;
            lock (queue)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(queue);
                toBeConsumed = queue.Dequeue();
            }
            // Do consuming stuff with toBeConsumed here.
        }
    }
}
```

What do we have here?

The producer produces an object whenever he feels like it. As soon as he has, he obtains lock on the queue, enqueues the object, then does a `Pulse` call.

At the same time, the consumer does NOT have lock, he left it by calling `Wait`. As soon as he gets a `Pulse` on that object, he will re-lock, and do his consuming stuff.

So what you have here is a direct thread-to-thread notification that there is something to do for the consumer. If you wouldn't have that, all you could do is have the consumer keep polling on the collection if there is something to do yet. Using `Wait`, you can make sure that there is.

Comment: From the other prospective answer "You can only call Monitor.Wait(Object), when you already own the lock". Can the consumer call Monitor.Wait(queue) when Producer has the lock?

Comment: The producer has the lock for a short time, the time it takes for a `Queue.Enqueue` and a `Monitor.Pulse` call, the latter dropping the lock. The consumer is either completely outside the lock block, which means he would just acquire the lock, call `Wait`, immediately stop waiting due to the lingering `Pulse`, or he is inside the `Wait` call, making him reacquire lock and do his consuming stuff.

Comment: According to the documentation on [Monitor.Pulse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse.aspx) that looks like a deadlock waiting to happen: "The Monitor class does not maintain state indicating that the Pulse method has been called. Thus, if you call Pulse when no threads are waiting, the next thread that calls Wait blocks as if Pulse had never been called. If two threads are using Pulse and Wait to interact, this could result in a deadlock. Contrast this with the behavior of the AutoResetEvent class[...]"

Comment: I went ahead and tried the example. http://ideone.com/ucE2PY - it does not deadlock (the producer keeps pulsing), but SOME pulses ARE lost nonetheless. The producer always produces more elements than the consumer consumes. Whenever the consumer is outside its `lock` block and the producer pulses, that pulse is lost.

Answer (score 1):

As Cristi mentioned, a naive wait/pulse code does not work. Because your are completely missing the crucial point here : The monitor is NOT a message queue. If you pulse and no one is waiting, the pulse is LOST. 
The right philosophy is that your are waiting for a condition, and if the condition is not satisfied, there is a way to wait for it, without eating cpu and without holding the lock. Here, the condition for the consumer is that there is something in the queue.
See https://ideone.com/tWqTS1 which work (a fork from by Cristi's example).

```
public class PulseWaitExample
{
    private Queue<object> queue;
    private bool running;

    private void ProducerThreadProc()
    {
        while (running)
        {
            object produced = ...; // Do production stuff here.
            lock (queue)
            {
                queue.Enqueue(produced);
                Monitor.Pulse(queue);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ConsumerThreadProc()
    {
        while (running)
        {
            object toBeConsumed;
            lock (queue)
            {
                // here is the fix
                if (queue.Count == 0)
                { 
                   Monitor.Wait(queue);
                }
                toBeConsumed = queue.Dequeue();
            }
            // Do consuming stuff with toBeConsumed here.
        }
    }
}
```